How can one delete several files at once in GitHub (online, via browser)?
I know one can delete one file in GitHub online via browser using:

but I wonder how one can delete several files at once in GitHub (online, via browser).

Select the branch you want to edit on GitHub, click on a file and in the file's edit menu select Open with... > github.dev. This will open a VS Code based web editor, where you can delete as many files as you want and then make a commit.

